# How to Import Another Python 3 File in Django Settings.py?

Tags: django, python-3.x, import, importerror, django-settings

I'm using Python 3.
I have two Python files in the same directory: first.py and second.py.
In the beginning of first.py, I use:

```
from second import *
```

However, it returns the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'second'
```

How should I import it in first.py?

**Update**: To clarify my specific use-case, I am trying to split my settings.py in Django. I have a main settings.py file and another one that only includes the confidential information. I followed [this following documentation](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings#Multiplesettingfilesimportingfromeachother) that uses the following line in settings.py:

```
from settings_local import *
```

Note that settings_local.py is in the same directory. However, it returns the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'settings_local'
```

I know the document says "Some of the examples listed below need to be modified for compatibility with Django 1.4 and later." but I do not know how to use it in Python 3.

Comment: Where are you running the script from? You should be able to import from Python files contained in the folder where you run the script. If you run the script from the same folder as the script, you shouldn't get this error.

Comment: Basically, I am trying to split my settings.py in Django. I have a main settings.py file and another one that only includes the confidential information. I followed the following documentation, but it does not work: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings#Multiplesettingfilesimportingfromeachother

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found the solution:

```
from .settings_local import *
```

instead of:

```
from settings_local import *
```

I found the solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python/73149#73149).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code snippet:

```
from .settings_local import *
```

This is relative import. [More Info here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#id11) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73149/3959965)

Answer (score 0):

You can add files into Python this way

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app/folder')
import file
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when the file is in the same path, why should I give it an absolute path?

Comment: There is more clarity in the absolute path :)

Answer (score 0):

```
you can create __init__.py in current directory.
```

then you can use:

```
from second import *
```

The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, **init**.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the __all__variable, described later.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to automatically add the directory the file is in to the `PATH`, and then import the other file, with this:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
import second
```